# Cast id to a long type crashes

Tags: ios, casting, long-integer

I'm trying to cast an id value, returned from a json, to a long value (timestamp purposes).

xcode sais me:

```
-[__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d3f220
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d3f220'
```

The next lines break the code.

```
long time_now = [self getTimestamp];
                    long fdate = [[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_first_date"] longValue];
                    long sdate = [[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_second_date"] longValue];
```

What I'm doing wrong? id type is not a dynamic type to be casted?

After your comments, this is my possible solution:

```
long long time_now = [self getTimestamp];
                    long long fdate = [(NSString *)[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_first_date"] longLongValue];
                    long long sdate = [(NSString *)[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_second_date"] longLongValue];
```

Comment: Yes, your edit shows a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a cast, it's a method invocation. And, you can't cast from `id` to `long` (well, you could, but it has very limited utility).

You're trying to ask an `NSString` to convert itself to a `long`, but it doesn't respond to `longValue`.

`NSString` does have a `longLongValue` method which you could use instead.

Comment: I've edit my question with a possibility. Read it if you can and comment. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's appropriate

Answer (score 1):

The selector is unrecognized because `longValue` is not a method in `NSString`. Use `longLongValue` instead.

```
long long fdate = [[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_first_date"] longLongValue];
long long nsdate = [[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_second_date"] longLongValue];
```

Here's a link to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/longLongValue).

Comment: This is what I do. Thanks. I suppose that it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility:

```
long long time_now = [self getTimestamp];
                    long long fdate = [(NSString *)[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_first_date"] longLongValue];
                    long long sdate = [(NSString *)[results2 objectForKey:@"pll_second_date"] longLongValue];
```